# Why send email use mail laravel does not work if it use shouldqueue?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, queue, laravel-5.3, laravel-mail

My mail laravel like this :

```
<?php
namespace App\Mail;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
class OrderReceivedMail extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $order;
    public $store;
    public function __construct($order, $store)
    {
        $this->order = $order;
        $this->store = $store;
        $this->subject('subject');
    }
    public function build()
    {
        $company_email = explode(',',config('app.mail_company'));
        return $this->view('vendor.notifications.mail.email-order-received',['number'=>$this->order->number, 'store_name' => $this->store->name])->bcc($company_email);
    }
}
```

My env like this :

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=redis

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

If the code executed, it does not works. The email failed sended or the mail code not executed

But if I remove `implements ShouldQueue`, it works. The email success sended

Why if I use shouldqueue it does not works?

Comment: Do you use homestead?

Comment: @lewis4u, How do I know I am using homestead or not? Where do I check it?

Comment: Homestead is a virtual machine where all software needed for Laravel is pre-installed. How do you work with Laravel? Which Operating System do you use (Windows, MAC OS, Linux)?

Comment: @lewis4u, In my localhost, I use windows

Comment: Sorry I don't use Windows so I can't help you further.

Comment: @lewis4u, Okay.No problem. In my localhost use windows. In my server seems use linux

Answer (score 0):

When using `ShouldQueue` your emails are not sent instantly. You need to run the queue worker `php artisan queue:work` as described here https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#running-the-queue-worker

Comment: But if he is not using homestead even that will not work! Especially if he is using Windows and XAMPP

Comment: I assume he has redis configured by the part of the env he provided. Btw. homestead is not a holy grail, he could be using laradock too :)

Comment: I assume he doesn't even know what is redis or what is homestead.

Comment: @veNuker, What is the use of shoulqueue? What is the advantage of using shoulqueue and what is the loss if not using shouldqueue

Comment: If you remove it, email is sent instantly. It is handled by the same php process, and is faster. The disadventage is, if something unexpected happens like exception, email is not sent and its data is lost, as it was kept in memory. ShouldQueue is saving email content to specified location like redis or hdd disk. It is sent by a different process when you run your queue with command specified in the answear.

Comment: @veNuker, Okay. Thanks for your answer. So if using shouldqueue, in localhost send email not automatic? It must run `php artisan queue:work` to sent email. Right? What if in staging or production server, will it be automatic?

Comment: Right. For production and staging, you also need to run this command `artisan queue:work`. Usually you do it with crontab, for laravel this is the recommended way - https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling